# Lattice reduction to find a solution to congruence equation

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I am implementing an algorithm to solve ternary quadratic equations. I have come to a situation where I have a congruence equation $X^2-aZ^2 \equiv 0 \ (mod \ b)$ with a known solution $(x_0, y_0) = (w, 1)$ and I want to find another non-trivial solution $(x_0, y_0)$ so that the quantity $x_0^2 + |a|^2z_0^2 $ is minimized. The source I am using asks to use a lattice reduction algorithm to do this. How can I implement such a algorithm? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your source should (hopefully!) give enough details to set up the lattice: It should provide you with $d$ basis vectors of dimension $d$ that define a $d$-dimensional lattice formed by all sums of integer multiples of the basis vectors.

For then performing the lattice reduction, the academic answer is often to use the Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász algorithm, often referred to as LLL. It provides a new set of basis vectors in polynomial time that fulfill a certain bound on their size. For a casual introduction that already includes numerical discussion and source code, I recommend [this blog from Kenneth Shum's scrapbook](http://home.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/~wkshum/wordpress/?p=442). For a more in-depth treatment, have a look at [this paper/homework with some application and implementation notes](http://algo.epfl.ch/_media/en/projects/bachelor_semester/rapportetiennehelfer.pdf).